# WPF. Лучший способ создания пользовательского элемента как совокупности нескольких разных стандартных элементов

Tags: c#, wpf

Какими инструментами WPF лучше всего сделать свой `Control`, состоящий из нескольких `Control'ов`, чтобы его можно было многократно использовать?

В качестве примера **Задача.** В окне WPF должны вводиться значения углов (или широты/долготы) в градусах, минутах и секундах. Таких значений около 5. Предполагается, что значения градусов, минут и секунд вводятся в отдельные `TextBox'ы`. Также к каждому текстовому полю есть подпись `Label`. Хотелось бы обернуть три эти текстовых поля в один контрол и использовать его в разметке.

Comment: чем обычный `User Control` не нравится?

Comment: @tym32167 с ним пока не работал, поэтому и спрашивал, какой способ будет лучше. Спасибо. А что из источников посоветуете почитать, где хорошо объясняется про `UserControl`?

Comment: да нет особых источников, просто нажимаете на вашем проекте правой кнопкой мыши -> Add -> User Control